# Windows Forms App: System.NullReferenceException Error

Tags: vb.net

Good day,

I have been trying to figure out the source of error in my application. What this function (`GetConcentrations()`) is to display data from my database onto a DataGridView. The function is called in the PageLoad but works fine but when I call it in another Sub, I get this error.

Could anyone help me? I already tried different ways.

Thanks!

[image]

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub GetConcentrations()
    Dim conString As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("dbAsthmaConnectionString").ConnectionString
    Me.dataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter("Select * from tblConcentrations", conString)
    'Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter("Select * from tblConcentrations", conString)
    Dim dataset As New Data.DataSet

    Try
        Dim commandBuilder As New SqlCommandBuilder(Me.dataAdapter)

        Dim table As New DataTable()
        table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
        Me.dataAdapter.Fill(table)
        'Dim datasetgetconcentrations = New DataSet
        Me.dataAdapter.Fill(dataset)
        Me.bindingSource1.DataSource = table

        DataGridView3.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCellsExceptHeader)

        DataGridView3.DataSource = dataset.Tables(0)

        dataset.Dispose()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Failed to display the concentration table (GetConcentrations)!", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    End Try

    'Dim ConcentrationValue As Double = DataGridView2.Rows.Contains
    'TextBoxCurrentConcentration.Text = txtMessage.Text
End Sub
```

Comment: Please post the code, not an image.  Also, show which line gets the exception.  Please also show the full call stack from the exception, if possible.

Comment: The `dataset.Dispose()` doesn't make a lot of sense since you appear to be using it for binding your controls.  BTW, posting an entire screen shot is hard to read.

Comment: Hi, I posted the code. It highlights             Me.dataAdapter.Fill(dataset)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you call the Fill method two times.
Once to fill a DataTable and one again to fill a DataSet. Only the one for the dataset is really needed.
Could you try if this changes something in your problem?

```
    Dim ds as New DataSet
    ds.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture 
    Me.dataAdapter.Fill(ds) 
    DataGridView3.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCellsExceptHeader) 
    DataGridView3.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
```

Also, don't dispose your dataset on exiting, you are still using it.
In this case it's better to let the Garbage Collection handle this task.